# Upload path and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] not working in cpanel with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have a project with CODEIGNITER where I have to upload files that is running well in localhost. But problem started when I uploaded the file into linux cpanel .file is not uploading also I have to find image from the folder that I did with the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/sliderImages/';  but that also not working in cpanel . i am unable to solve the problem !

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks in advance

Locally my file upload folder location is

```
     C:/wamp64/www/admin/sliderImages
```

and in cpanel its location is

```
    public_html/admin/sliderImages
```

here admin is my  project folder name under which there are all codeigniter file and folder .

i used upload path in codeigniter is

```
    $config['upload_path']          = './sliderImages/';
```

and to find all images in that folder i used

```
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/sliderImages/';

    $files = glob($path.'*'); // get all file names
```

so tell me or give me any link that how can i upload and fetch file from folder with codeigniter in cpanel that i did in localhost !

also i have 755 folder permission for the folder in cpanel .

when i uploaded my project in cpanel and trying to upload a image in the folder it's showing an error like

```
   Array ( [error] =>
      The upload path does not appear to be valid.

   )
```

Comment: come on someone pls tell me something !

Answer (score 1):

why not try using relative path from index.php as all of your code will be executing from index.php. So try

```
 $path = 'admin/sliderImages/';
 $files = scandir($path); // get all file names
```

Answer (score 0):

start with config file

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

This will make your upload path to be `base_url('admin/sliderImages');`
Let CI sort the urls and don't forget to endit the .htaccess file to reflect server configs

Comment: sorry @clifford_owino ! i changed like $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/admin/'; because if do exactly like you i have to change it too many place to run my site . so i did this      $config['upload_path']          = base_url('sliderImages/'); but result is same ! not uploading !

Comment: copy your upload code here so that we can help debug what we are seeing